# Cannot get Android Studio to ignore changes files when committing to GitHub

Tags: android, github, ignore

I am using Android Studio 1.3.2 under Windows 7 in combination with GitHub.
I would like changes made (most often automatically) in some files (class, apk, bin, etc.) and directories (build, etc.) to be ignored.
I have tried putting a ".gitignore" in the project folder and also using the "configure ignored files" button of the "version control" panel, but changes I would like to ignore still seem to get detected in the build folder for instance.
Can anybody recommend the right way to do this?
Regards,
SV

Answer (score 1):

first, `add` the files you need and exclude the ones you don't (after the add) with `git checkout .` (yes, with the dot). Sadly, those files get modify every time and you must exclude if don't need it to push.